# Problema con funcionamiento botones Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: bootstrap-4

estoy usando Bootstrap 4.0 y tengo problemas para que un boton input se marque cuando esta presionado y no salga el checkbox sino sólo el botón. Es decir, cuando presiono el botón se marca pero sale el checkbox y según veo no debería salir dicho checkbox y en su lugar debería el botón estar sombreado (como este ejemplo: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#toggle-states) Este es el código:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
       <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"  name="" id=""> Checkbox 1
    </label>
</div>
```

Las librerias js y css de Bootstrap se cargan correctamente asi como el jquery. ¿Por qué podría estar fallando?

Comment: Estas seguro que las librerías se cargan?, lo has comprobado en el código fuente de la página?- Indica también el Controlador donde devuelves la Vista, puede que estés devolviendo una Vista parcial.

Comment: Si, tanto bootstrap.js como jquery.jss y bootstrap.css se cargan. Estoy probando sin controlador ni vista. Es un ejemplo básico de bootstrap (solo html,css y js).

Comment: Has probado a inspeccionar el elemento con F12 y ver si los estilos son los correctos?. Y también la consola de JavaScript del navegador a ver si salta algún error.

Comment: Rafael, tienes toda la razón. Acabo de revisar y encontré que era un fallo en la carga de librerias por una errata. Gracias!